# In Redux, why do you need a seperate reducer to manage the other reducers (as shown in documentation)

Tags: redux, state, reducers

http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/CoreConcepts.html

As shown in the bottom of the document, a separate reducer was created to manage the previously created reducers.

I am very new to redux and am not understanding the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a design pattern in Redux. As noted further on in the docs [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html), Redux lets you do *reducer composition*, which lets different reducers handle different slices of the state. From the docs:

> Note that each of these reducers is managing its own part of the global state. The state parameter is different for every reducer, and corresponds to the part of the state it manages.

As your application grows larger, it will make sense to logically split up reducers to make your application easier to comprehend, and combine them back together. Redux supplies `combineReducers()` to help you do this. In Redux's Todo app example, as found [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html), there is a reducer to handle todos, one to handle the visibility filter for todos, and a reducer that combines them with `combineReducers()`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a global state that looks like this

```
{
    routing : some data,
    restaurants : some_data ,
    user : some_data,
    neighborhood : some_data,
}
```

You can handle everything in one big reducer, or otherwise you handle each part in a different reducer.

You could have a look at an example here: https://github.com/maxgallo/deliveroo/blob/master/src/js/reducers/index.js